# Dask[dataframe] "requirements are not installed" on AWS lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, dask, dask-dataframe

Trying to use dask.dataframe in AWS lambda. But in-spite of bundling dask.dataframe as part of bundle, I repeatedly see this error :

> ImportError: Dask dataframe requirements are not installed.
>
> Please either conda or pip install as follows:
>
> conda install dask                     # either conda install
> python -m pip install "dask[dataframe]" --upgrade  # or python -m pip
> install

Tried the following:

1. Bundling dask[complete] and uploading it as aws lambda layer
2. Bundling dask[dataframe] and uploading it as aws lambda layer
3. Bundling the code and dependencies and placing in s3 bucket

**python version 3.8**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One potential error is that dask dataframe is not installed on worker instances. There are some possible solutions [here](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/1200).

I don't have much experience with running dask on Lambda with custom environments, but I used `coiled` to run dask-based code on Lambda. Using `coiled-runtime` gives a robust set of packages and there is an easy way to run `dask` using your own AWS account/credentials, see [docs](https://docs.coiled.io/user_guide/backends_aws.html#using-your-own-aws-account).